# Enable mat-tab scroll without arrows

Tags: angular, material-design, carousel, mat-tab

I am willing to reproduce tabs scrollable with a finger on mobile like Google page:

[image]

But with mat-tab (Material Design & Angular), I have two arrows displaying:

[image]

I managed to remove the arrows with `disablePagination = true`, however scrolling with finger is not working:

[image]

Anyone has a solution to make it work?

Code:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Fourth"> Content 4 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Fifth"> Content 5 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Sixth"> Content 6 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Seventh"> Content 7 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Eight"> Content 8 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Nineth"> Content 9 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tenth"> Content 10 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Eleventh"> Content 11 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Twelves"> Content 12 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Thirteenth"> Content 13 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Forteenth"> Content 14 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Try to enable overflow and customise overflow control bar to be like tab color.

Comment: @Radeanu thanks for advice! Would you have some ressources to redirect me to do this?

Comment: My example: https://codepen.io/radeanu/pen/yLVLMMY   Go to mobile for it to work.

Comment: @Radeanu Nice workaround, but it doesn't solve my issue since I would loose benefits of mat-tab, especially the beautiful style (underlying, focus, ripples)

Comment: I need the same. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I hope someone can use this:

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-header-pagination-controls-enabled .mat-tab-header-pagination {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the disabled arrow you can also do that (in your case the left arrow it's disabled and does nothing at the moment). Also when you go to the last tab, the right arrow will be disabled.
[image]

```
mat-tab-header .mat-tab-header-pagination:disabled { display: none; }
```